# Bootstrap is very slow how to make it faster

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My site is : [Design Spicy](http://designspicy.com)

my website is slow during the bootstrap.css and js

Load time :  3.56s  (**by pingdom**)
bootstrap.css  : 97.9 kB
bootstrap.js : 28.7

**by Google pagespeed Checker**

```
Compressing http://designspicy.com/…tent/themes/desgnspycy/css/bootstrap.css could save 80.8KiB (82% reduction).
Compressing http://designspicy.com/…content/themes/desgnspycy/js/jquery-1.js could save 59.3KiB (64% reduction).
Compressing http://designspicy.com/…ontent/themes/desgnspycy/js/bootstrap.js could save 20.9KiB (73% reduction).
Compressing http://designspicy.com/ could save 10.8KiB (74% reduction).
Compressing http://designspicy.com/wp-content/themes/desgnspycy/style.css could save 5.9KiB (70% reduction).
```

i uses bootstrap for mobile optimize css but my site load time is low any suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another suggestion is using a content delivery network, or `CDN`, that hosts your files like `Bootstrap` and `jQuery`. That way, if a user has already visited a site where Bootstrap (or jQuery) is loaded using the same CDN, those files will be cached in the browser.

Another advantage of CDN? They tend to be optimized for quick delivery of such files to users (for ex., based on location of user, the CDN decides the best server/ fastest - to the user...)

A quick Google search points to this CDN for Bootstrap: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: may i use W3 Total Cache ? for speed ? with out CDN ?

Comment: For WordPress, you should look into some form of caching (to lessen the load of your DB), but as far as your question, without the CDN, you'll lose the benefit of W3 Total Cache and static files.

Comment: Thanx @Jack Pattishall Jr. for best suggestion i will try with cdn and w3 total cache :)

Answer (score 3):

As pagespeed says, enable gzip compression (for textual content -- many image formats are already compressed) in your web server. How to do it depends on what server you run; for Apache httpd 2.2, an incantation like

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE \
  text/html text/plain text/xml application/xhtml+xml \
  text/css \
  text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

will compress your usual suspects as they're transmitted to the client.

Comment: i uses hostgator for hosting. site on wordpress platform. where to place this code ? or any suggestion...

Comment: This helped me. Even the official CDN was slow.

Answer (score 1):

Analyse your classes and its properties in CSS of bootstrap.There can be many properties which may be not needed for you. So you can remove that freely. And make a single class for commonly initialized properties. So your code will be reduced. And this can affect your page speed. Thanks.